# Get the size of a folder in Google Cloud using PHP client

Tags: php, size, directory, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I want to get the size of a folder in Google Cloud. I know I can do this by retrieving all files and loop through the files and summarize all files sizes, but this is a time consuming action. I want to do this through an API.

Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You'd either need to compute it when needed or keep a running tally via notifications.